# Instances of javafx.scene.Cursor cannot be created by FXML

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

it s my first time to use javafx  a create a  frame  with SceneBuilder-8.5.0 but  there is this  error :
Instances of javafx.scene.Cursor cannot be created by FXML loader.
any solution ??

[image]

Comment: Could you add any info on how you got to this? `Cursor` is `abstract` and cannot be instantiated for this reason, but there are several constants that can be used to assign a `Cursor`...

Comment: As mentioned, [`javafx.scene.Cursor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Cursor.html#cursor(java.lang.String)) is an abstract class and as such cannot be directly instantiated. However, you can reference one of the constants (i.e. one of the public, static, final fields) available using [`fx:constant`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements).